# mod_python publisher and pretty URLs

Tags: python, url, mod-python, friendly-url

I am new to Python (I am getting out of PHP because of how increasingly broken it is), and I am racing through porting my old code. One thing:

I have a file /foo.py with functions index() and bar(), so, with the publisher I can access http://domain/foo/bar and http://domain/foo as the documentation suggests.

How can I have it such that I can do:

http://domain/foo/bar/a1/a2/a3/an/...

Such that the publisher launches bar() and then I can access the URL to obtain /a1/a2/... 
All I get is Forbidden :) (I don't want to use mod_rewrite on everything)

Oh, im on 2.5.2
Thanks in advance

UPDATE: The ideal solution would be for the publisher to launch the furthest-right resolution in the URL it can, and simply make a1/a2/a3.. accessible through the apache module. Maybe a combination of an apache directive and publisher?

SOLVED (ish):
The answer of the magic **call**() method and so on is juicy! Although I think I will modify the publisher or write my own to inspect objects in a similar way using furthest-right matching, then allowing the furthest-right to access the URL using apache module. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to have an object `bar.a1.a2.a3.an` defined within your `foo.py` module. Basically, the publisher handler replaces the slashes in the URL with dots, and tries to find some Python object with that name.

Here's something wacky you could try: in `foo.py`:

```
class _barclass(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, name):
        if parent and name:
            self.path = parent.path + '/' + name
            setattr(parent, name, self)
        else:
            self.path = ''
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return _barclass(self, name)
    def __call__(self):
        # do your processing here
        # url path is contained in self.path

bar = _barclass(None, None)
```

Although this is kind of straining the bounds of what the publisher is meant to do - you might be better off writing your own handlers from scratch. (Or using something like Django.)

Comment: This would be a headache, as the a1,a2,a3 components are likely labels from a database:

foo/articles/may/2009/latest

for articles() mixing database info and a constraint 'latest'

Coding all this into an object nest would suck :)

Thanks anyway!

Comment: :) I didnt, and the magic methods seem much more up my street

Comment: You get my green! I should have thought of this, not used to jumping to the dynamicism of objects (although PHP supported it, badly) I am mostly a C man! Thanks

Comment: I know what you mean, Python has a lot of tricks that take some time to get used to. (I've been at it for a year and a half now.)

Comment: 6 hours in :(, Although once the whole white-space deal gets comfy I will be glad to see the back of PHP. At the moment though I want my braces back :)

Comment: Well, stick with it! I also converted my website from PHP to Python, back in December, and I've never regretted it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is beyond the capabilities of the publishing algorithm, as far as I know. ([The documentation certainly doesn't mention it.](http://www.modpython.org/live/mod_python-3.3.1/doc-html/hand-pub-alg-trav.html)) You could write your own mod_python handler ([example here](http://www.modpython.org/live/mod_python-3.3.1/doc-html/tut-404-handler.html)) that extends the publishing algorithm to do so, however.

A better solution would be to look into [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) and build your web application as an [WSGI application](http://www.wsgi.org/wsgi/) instead. You would benefit from the shelves and shelves of WSGI middleware, but in particular you'd be able to use routing software like [Routes](http://routes.groovie.org/), which are specifically designed to handle these cases where object publishing isn't strong enough. But I don't know your deadlines, so this may or may not be feasible.

Comment: Thanks Hao Lian:

I think an app framework or middleware bulkier than publisher is overkill. In PHP i simply exploded $_SERVER[url_key_thing] and I thin Apache recognized that /foo/bar/a/b/c didn't exist but that /foo/bar did (as a file) and ran it.

Maybe there is an Apache directive?

Comment: @NewToPython: Sounds like you're thinking of PATH_INFO - you can use that in Python too but but with the publisher handler.

Comment: Mod_Python's implementation is actually pretty bulky. You'd probably find that WSGI + Routes (or something else) might actually be faster and lighter.

Comment: And I'd point out that the url explosion approach, with Apache "just running" the resulting file is representative of one of the underlying aspects of the PHP culture that has led to you thinking it is broken :-)

Comment: @Jarret - I know *shame*, although I didn't presume the publisher was broken, just didn't know if it implemented a similar resolution mechanism and I couldn't find it!